# Is it possible to have another loop within a class in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

Is it possible to have another loop within a class in Processing?

In the main class, I can have a `draw()` function that runs on every frame. But I want to have the same thing for my other classes so that I don't have to dump every thing that I have run every frame in the main class. It also keeps my code cleaner.

This is what I have tried which didn't really quite work:

This is the class that I have:

```
public class MyClass {

  private int backgroundColour = 0;

  public MyClass () {
  }

  public void draw() {
    background(backgroundColour++, 0, 0);
    println(backgroundColour);
  }
}
```

And if I were to instantiate this in my main class like so:

```
MyClass myClass;
void setup() {
  myClass = new MyClass();
}
```

I don't see the colour changing and the line printing on the console on every frame. Of course, I could call `myClass.draw()` in the `draw()` function of my main class, but like I said, I wish I could let the dependent classes handle their own stuff within themselves.

So, coming from an Actionscript background, I'm trying to achieve something like to have another "ENTER_FRAME" of sort in a class which I will instantiate in the main class, except that I'm doing this in Processing. Is it possible to do this in Processing?

Comment: Sure it is probably possible, show us what you have tried.

Comment: @user2310289 Okay, sure. I have updated my question with what I have done to try this so far.

Comment: I'm trying to understand but since I don't have any actionscript experience its not very simple... Are you trying to say you want a class to draw itself without you calling its draw() function? Sort of like in a parallel universe?

Comment: If I understand correctly from what google says, with "ENTER_FRAME" you attach a listener to a stage which with the entrance of a new frame does something. Then you don't need to call that something in each frame because, well, the listener does? So somebody has to call that function anyway.. If its a matter of style (code clutter etc) there are probably more "java-style" ways...

Comment: @PetrosKoutsolampros I'm trying to work in Processing. I was drawing ideas from my experience with Flash. What I need is something like in another class or object, I want it to be able to have its "own" frame loop of sort.

Comment: Your life will be many times simpler if you stick with calling `.display()` from the main `loop()`, Processing lends itself to that style of programming.

Comment: @kevinsa5 Oh well.. looks like I have to follow Processing's style. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Try this code:

```
import processing.core.*;

public class MyClass implements PConstants {

  PApplet parent;
  private int backgroundColour = 0;

  public MyClass (PApplet parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    parent.registerMethod("draw", this);
  }

  public void draw() {
    parent.background(backgroundColour++, 0, 0);
    parent.println(backgroundColour);
  }
}
```

And instantiate passing "this" as argument

```
MyClass myClass;
void setup() {
  myClass = new MyClass(this);
}
```

You should follow this tutorial https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Library-Basics

Comment: Read this forum too http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/how-to-register-methods-in-processing-2b1.html. 
The tutorial I posted is for the an old Processing version, so if you want to use the mouseEvent and the keyEvent without getting copiling errors, you should use the "new method"